# Cypress 7: onRequest in cy.intercept issue

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation, e2e-testing

We have following code that asserts there was a spinner showing up when there was a request:

Following code works ok in cypress 6.4.0

```
cy.intercept({
  url: '*',
  onRequest: () => {
    cy.get('[data-testid=spinner-loading-indicator]')
    .should('exist')
  }, 
});
```

With cypress 7.5.0 though, `onRequest` is no longer valid
The most similar thing we found was

```
cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
  req.on('before:response', (res) => {
     cy.get('[data-testid=spinner-loading-indicator]').should('exist')
  })
})
```

This returns an error since Cypress doesn't allow promises here (cy.get() being a promise)

Has anyone faced a similar issue, and if solved then how?

Answer (score 3):

You could change

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=spinner-loading-indicator]').should('exist')
```

to this

```js
expect(Cypress.$('[data-testid=spinner-loading-indicator]')).to.exist
```

The difference is the 2nd (jQuery) test does not retry - not exactly sure if that's going to be a problem, can't tell what the order of events are from your question.

---

Testing the loading indicator inside the intercept feels a bit like testing two things at once, but timing might make things flaky for you (especially in CI)

Is there any reason why this sequence is no good?

```js
cy.intercept('*').as('requested')

// trigger events
cy.visit('some-url')       // if initiated on load
// or
cy.get('button').click()   // if user-initiated

cy.wait('@requested')      
cy.get('[data-testid=spinner-loading-indicator]').should('exist')
```

---

In terms of events, the firing of the routeHandler `(req) => {...}` *is* the onRequest event, but you're still not able to call commands inside,

i.e this is logically equivalent to the `onRequest` syntax,

```js
cy.intercept('*', (req) => {
  cy.get('[data-testid=spinner-loading-indicator]')        // throws an error 
})
```